Why am I now getting "ovpnagent: request error" from OpenVPN Connect?
I've been using OpenVPN Connect for over a year now without issue to connect to a server that I control.
This week, I started getting "Error message: ovpnagent: request error" when trying to connect.
There have been no changes to my knowledge on either end of this connection.
I have...

rebooted the VPN server & my machine.
confirmed OpenVPN Access Server is active/running.
reissued my connection token.
tail'd the openvpnas.log file and watched my connection attempt.  It says Auth Success.

There is one piece of the openvpn.log I don't understand.  What does this mean?  (highly redacted):

What else can I try? What is my issue here?  Thanks!

A new update to OpenVPN just dropped.  I installed that and now it's working!
